# React: Calling setState within render method throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title suggests, only after the first message received in my chat-window - this initial message is retrieved from a GET request so it's not synchronous -  I want to show/render a button. At the moment it throws an error saying I cant set the state within the render method.

I also tried the show logic in the button class as well as the 'parent' class which is my messagelist which I'm putting the button in its render method.

There is this.props.messages which is an array of the messages and so is 'messages'.  this.props.messages[0].data.text is the first message, although it does console many times each messsage in the dev tools when i try console it, and of course it throws the setState error when i try to show the button.

I have a simple button class:

```
class Button extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {<button>Return</button >}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Button;
```

and my messageList class, where I have the this.props.messages which is an array of the messages, this.props.messages[0] is the first message , and message..which console's every single message if i console.log it.

If i write either (if message.data.text OR this.props.messages[0] === 'my first string') { console.log ('..... '}then it always counts as true and consoles and the setstate goes into a loop.

```
import Message from './Messages'
import Button from './Button'


class MessageList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showing: false,
    };
    this.showButton = this.showButton.bind(this);
  }

  showButton() {
    const { showing } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      // toggle value of `showing`
      showing: !showing,

    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    this.scrollList.scrollTop = this.scrollList.scrollHeight;
  }

  onlyInitialMessage(message) {
    if (this.props.messages[0].data.text = `Hi I'm Joe your store assistant, I'm here to help. Here's what I can do: Answer questions on store policies, process a return or just general inquiries.`) {
      this.showButton();
    }
  }

  // way to render a function.
  // {this.renderIcon()}   


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sc-message-list" ref={el => this.scrollList = el}>
        {this.props.messages.map((message, i) => {

          { this.onlyInitialMessage() }

          return <Message message={message} key={i} />
        })}

        {this.state.showing && <Button />}

      </div>)
  }
}
```

I'm not sure If I have my logic in the wrong place here? I tried to move it around lots of times, I am new to React!

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly**, The issue is that you are setting state in the render method indirectly by calling `{ this.onlyInitialMessage() }` in render.

**Secondly**, your if condition is not comparing value but assinging value which will always return true

```
if (this.props.messages[0].data.text === `Hi I'm Joe your store assistant, I'm here to help. Here's what I can do: Answer questions on store policies, process a return or just general inquiries.`) {
```

To solve it, you must call `onlyInitialMessage` within componentDidMount

```
import Message from './Messages'
import Button from './Button'


class MessageList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showing: false,
    };
    this.showButton = this.showButton.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.onlyInitialMessage();
  }
  showButton() {
    const { showing } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      // toggle value of `showing`
      showing: !showing,

    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    this.scrollList.scrollTop = this.scrollList.scrollHeight;
  }

  onlyInitialMessage(message) {
    if (this.props.messages[0].data.text == `Hi I'm Joe your store assistant, I'm here to help. Here's what I can do: Answer questions on store policies, process a return or just general inquiries.`) {
      this.showButton();
    }
  }

  // way to render a function.
  // {this.renderIcon()}   


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sc-message-list" ref={el => this.scrollList = el}>
        {this.props.messages.map((message, i) => {

          return <Message message={message} key={i} />
        })}

        {this.state.showing && <Button />}

      </div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, my initial message is retrieved from a GET request so it's not synchronous, with the componentDidMount - nothing appears! It comes back if I comment it out.

Comment: Ok, then what you need to do is call setState in componentDidUpdate after checking if the props actually changed

Comment: I get - 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'... It's a chat-window so the messages arent already there they are returned via request.

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll have a go at that, I'm guessing I can find resources on how to do that online?